# Would a moist cloth wrapped around the nose be reasonably effective as compared to an anti-pollution mask?

Tags: commuter, accessories, pollution

On looking at the [prices of masks and filters](http://store.bumsonthesaddle.com/collections/anti-pollution-masks), I figured that it could eventually get rather expensive for me. Moreover, there's an [article in a newspaper](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/bengaluru/Dont-be-fooled-by-safety-masks/articleshow/516980511.cms) that these masks don't really help:

> **Don't be fooled by safety masks (Sep 30, 2001)**
>   According to a
>   two-year painstaking study conducted by a group of researchers in the
>   department of chemical engineering, Indian Institute of Science, no
>   mask being sold in Bangalore is effective against the most common and
>   harmful pollutants: carbon monoxide (co), sulphur dioxide (so2),
>   suspended particulate matter (spm), oxides of nitrogen (nox). The
>   study, commissioned by the council for scientific and industrial
>   research (csir), has been examining all the material used in the
>   filters inside the plastic masks. To their utter dismay, researchers
>   found that people using these masks are being fooled beyond
>   imagination. says senior scientific officer Mr.J.R. Mudakavi: "we have
>   tested more than a dozen such masks available in the city's markets. I
>   am sorry to see that none of them informs the buyer what it is
>   effective against, what load it can take, if the filter is recyclable,
>   et al". The most injurious of all, CO, is not filtered by any mask.
>   sulphur dioxide is absorbed by some filters to some extent, but given
>   its concentration in the atmosphere, these masks are effective only
>   for 2-3 hours. no user is told that if the filter is washed it can be
>   used efficaciously a few more times. one of the dreaded pollutants is
>   spm (small particles from industry, stone crushing, construction
>   materials, exhaust, etc) which when inhaled in large quantity gets
>   deposited in the lungs and can cause silicosis.

Ok, so if even the anti-pollution masks can't filter out CO or SO2 properly, then that leaves the danger of the particulate matter which in my opinion, could be prevented with just a cloth wrapped around the nose and mouth.

Not a thin layer of cloth. A cloth where the folds form a couple of layers over your face and nose. If this cloth is moistened a bit, shouldn't it be effective against particulate matter.

For a short ride of maybe 30 minutes, won't a simple cloth be more cost effective and offer a reasonable amount of protection against pollutants?

Comment: It would probably be about as bad as most of the masks, even expensive ones.  Many of the particulates are rather small and a mask that allows you to breathe hard while filtering them out properly needs to be well engineered and *very* close fitting (basically useless with facial hair for example).

Comment: The cloth will do almost nothing. The question you need to answer is whether you want "better than nothing" or more, and what you're willing or able to spend. Better masks will have reusable filters but the filters are still a consumable and they generally don't have a useful wear indicator. My welding filters (multiple types depending on what I most want to filter out) are rated for X hours at Y airflow, and I just have to throw them out after X hours because there's no way to tell when they stop working. Road masks will be the same, wear it one day, wash it, reuse it, throw it out.

Comment: @Mσᶎ Nothing? Cloth will filter any particle bigger than the pours in the cloth.  Have you ever driven cattle?   If you get hit with tear gas the yes pull your shirt (and jacket) up over you face will help.  And don't weld on a bicycle.

Comment: @Frisbee normally I don't engage with you, but in this case I feel obliged to note that the *pores* in cloth are typically 0.1mm or larger, wqhich ill filter visible dust and ash only. That's not particularly useful. Wetting the cloth helps a lot, but is impractical while riding IME.

Comment: @Mσᶎ And I feel obligated to point out I stated particles bigger than the pours in the cloth. Visible particles do happen and are irritants so I do not accept it is not useful.    Typically - "folds form a couple of layers" - do you think the OP was gong to chose a gunny sack.  A mask is practical?

Comment: The problem is that you can't ride very well with most masks/respirators (even a regular n95 mask, which doesn't do anything for CO and stuff). They're very difficult to breathe with. Read [this article from OSHA](https://www.osha.gov/dts/shib/respiratory_protection.pdf).

Comment: No mechanical filter will remove gasses that are mixed with air.  Carbon monoxide, SO2, and NOX are gasses.  For these chemicals you need a heavy mask utilizing activated charcoal or some such.  As to particulate matter, a "HEPA" mask would generally suffice, and a relatively thick (multilayer) dampened cloth might work fairly well, but cheap paper masks are apt to be nearly useless.  But keep in mind that most masks will make it *much* more difficult to breathe.

Comment: The OP never said he was intending on biking with this mask substitute.  Is this question related to bicycles in any way?

Comment: @Criggie: Good catch. The query was because I ride a bicycle on polluted roads, but this could of course be extended to the times I am on a motorcycle. Everyone: A friend tried inserting cotton into his nostrils, but complained it kept falling off :) So I assume the moist cloth idea would be effective at least to some extent... Sometimes, the polluted air makes my eyes burn too. Daniel: HEPA = expensive. But really, I wish they hadn't killed electric vehicles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsJAlrYjGz8

Comment: Despite what I said before, it should be noted that a dampened cloth will have a modest effectiveness against SO2, since SO2 dissolves readily in water.  Whether this would amount to reducing SO2 by 90% or only 0.9%, though, I can't say.  A more effective mask could probably be made by including some other chemical with the water, but I don't know what that would be, and the chemical would likely have its own safety issues as well.  (CO is also soluble in water, but less so.)

Answer (score 3):

> **that leaves the danger of the particulate matter which in my opinion, could be prevented with just a cloth wrapped around the nose and mouth.**

Diesel particulates are mostly in the [3-30 nanometre](http://www.me.umn.edu/centers/mel/reports/dbkucdavis.pdf) range of sizes. This is very fine and will not be stopped by normal cloth.

3M [say](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/819050O/respiratory-protection-from-diesel-particulate-sept-2012.pdf) a P2 (EU rating) filter should reduce exposure to diesel particulates. A P3 mask should remove a higher proportion of particles. I suspect these filters might not remove the finer diesel particulates.

Most of these masks are not intended to supply a large volume of air, they are workplace masks not sports masks.

Some cycling mask makers write about PM10 filtering. Note that [PM10 are coarse dust particles](http://www.airnow.gov/index.cfm?action=aqibasics.particle) 2500 to 10000 nanometers in size. That's a lot larger than most diesel particulates.

The key to an effective filter is a good air-tight closure against the skin around the entire perimeter of the filter. You cannot obtain the necessary fit using cloth alone.

If [anecdotal stories](http://www.londoncyclist.co.uk/cycling-masks-and-the-shocking-results/) have anything to teach it is that you should expect a white filter to become blackened even on short rides and that you therefore need to replace the filter every ride.

Comment: my experience was similar to that, even using the respro. You just have to budget for a new set of filters every day or to, and buy them accordingly. Respro don't sell 100 packs of filters.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The typical "pollution mask" I have seen are modified or styled after surgical masks.  Surgical masks are NOT designed to filter intake air.  They are designed to direct exhaust air away from a patient who is opened up and vulnerable to infection.  The masks shown on your links appear to have possibly a sealing face mask, but the filters look clearly inadequate.

To properly filter air, you will need a mask that seals around your mouth and nose and has a proper one way valve(es) and appropriate filters.  Interior Alaska has some of the poorest air quality in the world during both the winter (inversion layer) and summer (forest fires) months.  What I have taken to using are the rather inexpensive "paint style" masks that [3M](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/3M-Safety-NA/Safety/Product-Catalog/~/3M-Paint-Project-Respirator-6000-Series?N=5927440%203294427653%203294529207&rt=rud) and other companies make that are available from home improvement stores like Home Depot.  The masks are rated for organic vapors and have replaceable filters, although I find it easier to simply replace the whole mask.

As for the difficulty breathing in these masks, I find that I cannot get enough air through them to maintain a full sprint, however, I can get enough to maintain a "race pace".  After a bit of use, I get even less air, or I can change the prefilters and filters and get back to where I started.

Comment: So the ordinary masks which are designed so stylishly and advertised so well, are just a farce! It's sad that we have to use something like a paint style mask for cycling. It's even more sad that the problem could've been solved in 1996, but was killed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsJAlrYjGz8

Comment: Your link is unrelated.  Forest fires are a naturally occurring part of the ecology in the subarctic landscape.  The "fire zone" of midnorthern Alaska has more acreage on fire any given summer than the rest of the lower 48 combined.  The result smoke pools in calmer bowl type areas like the valley that Fairbanks lays in.     http://www.latimes.com/nation/la-na-western-wildfires-20150817-story.html

Comment: Electric cars partly solve one part of the problem. Trucks, stationary energy plants (especially coal) and residential burning are a bigger problem. Finding a mask that's both effective and affordable is hard, as Sus User says. I've tried a powered mask and that was better, but it wasn't designed to provide airflow for a sprint. And it cost a lot.

Comment: @SuspendedUser: Agreed, there are natural sources of pollution. All I'm saying is that it's silly that we have to wear masks when we had found ways of keeping the air clean in the 90's itself.

Comment: @Nav I have never worn a respirator to filter out anthropogenic pollution.  Even if every car on the road was electric, I'd still have to wear a respirator for weeks every summer when the forest fires start.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I would make decisions based on masks available in the city markets of Bangalore.

You need to decide what is reasonable for you.  A cloth is not going to be as effective as a mask designed for particulate matter (and other pollutants).  Cloth will only get large particles and nothing for other pollutants.  But large particle is better than no particles.  On a dusty trail most particles are large.  If you get 40% that is still 40%.

As for CO and SO2. If there is source (delivering dangerous levels) of CO or SO2 then don't ride there.

If there are pollutants in your area then what about the 23 1/2 hours in the day?

Comment: "If there is source of CO of or SO2 then don't ride there." So, no cycling on roads, then!

Comment: @DavidRicherby A source and the source is not the same.  If the ROAD is producing CO or SO2 then it is the SOURCE and you should not be riding on that road.  What is the chemistry by which a road produces CO or SO2?  In the atmosphere and source are not the same.   With any gas you will have a higher concentration near the source - avoid that source.  Does that not seem prudent to you?   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/source

Comment: The source is the motor vehicles using the road.

Comment: OK the source is cars.  If it is too high then don't ride there.  So you take that as any level of source?  Come on man.

Comment: Keep in mind that ones respiration rate when cycling is several times more than when riding in a car, and ones time exposure is typically 2-4 times greater.  So conditions that are only moderately bad for driving to work can be incredibly bad when cycling.

Comment: CO binds more easily than O2 in blood. To move you need O2. If you can keep going on your bike that means you're getting all the O2 that you need and the concentration of CO2 is basically harmless. Think of it as alternative to altitude training J

Comment: @DanielRHicks Really?  It is distance squared?  So my VO2 to do 4 miles is 4 times my V02 to do 2 miles?  Old, tired, crazy.

Comment: @imel96 I would not use CO blocking O2 for *altitude* training.  CO is cumulative - not safe.  CO does not just bond - it is not readily displaced by O2.

Comment: @Frisbee: the half-life for CO in the blood is about 4-6 hours, CO is a naturally occurring byproduct of metabolism in small quantities and the body has ways of dealing with it, it's not like heavy metal poisoning.

Comment: @Frisbee - I don't understand what you're trying to say.  You breathe harder when cycling vs driving, and, typically, your speed is 2-4x faster in a car than when cycling, so less time exposed in the car.  Put together harder breathing for a longer time and you have a MUCH higher exposure cycling vs driving.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The stated question is a 30 minute bike ride.  And my answer only (attempts) to address that.  During that ride a cloth will at best filter large particles.   Exposure driving a fixed distance in a car versus a bicycle is neither the question nor my answer.

Comment: @whatsisname 4-6 hours is cumulative.  It is exactly like heavy metal poising but with a different time frame.  In the context of a 30 minute ride and I would stay away from a CO leak.  Would you use a CO tank for altitude training?   Would you work in closed garage with a car running?  Yes CO is naturally occurring but it does not take much to kill you.  In a refinery we wear CO meters and even near a car exhaust pipe it will go off.  A cloth is not going to filter CO as I stated. I don't ride in heavy traffic -  if you want to because your body will deal with CO then fine.

Comment: @Frisbee just anecdotal facts, people are doing physical in heavily polluted **outdoor** areas, 30 minute is nothing. Even if they get elevated CO level in their blood, the effect would be similar to being in altitude tent, you get less O2. It's not practical to do it safely because you'd need to monitor your blood. If people can race in the **Tour of Beijing**, surely these gasses in polluted air is not much of a problem, unlike lead poisoning which has long term effect.

Comment: @imel96 Tour of Beijing is evidence CO is harmless?  How about lead poisoning - any lead poisoning in Tour of Beijing - if not does that mean lead is harmless?  CO is poisonous gas  and cumulative is not the same as long term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide

Comment: @Frisbee by harmless I mean in the context of the question, riding bike outdoor, not dying in garage with a car with engine running. If the level is so high, the first effect would be your aerobic system not performing well from O2 deprivation. The link to wiki page you gave also shows a map of CO concentration. Although it doesn't illustrate specific area, it shows what kind of CO level in China compare to India. So, yes, I won't be concerned about CO.

Comment: @imel96 In the context of my answer I said "If there is source (delivering dangerous levels) of CO".  It can happen.  Fine don't be concerned about CO.  If it was in the context of the question then why the reference to lead?  In the context of the comment I said CO leak.